# Cannot rearrange Launchpad Icons

Tags: macos, launchpad

I just installed Lion over Snow Leopard.  I was trying to rearrange the icons in Launchpad into folders/groups.  It worked for a while, but sometime in the middle of rearranging I could no longer take previously foldered/grouped icons out of the group I had previously put them.

I performed the killall tutorial to reset Launchpad, only to have to start over again.  I tried restarting, etc., but I ran into the same problem again after a while of rearranging.

I cannot find anything online regarding being locked out of rearranging in Launchpad.  Has anyone else had this problem?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you the system admin?

Answer (score 2):

You can either...

- [nuke the Launchpad data and start clean](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/25/lion-deleting-apps-in-launchpad-and-starting-clean/) or
- [refresh the Launchpad database to get all apps loaded and movable](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/21/how-to-refresh-os-x-lions-launchpad-contents/).

Let me know which one works.